# Test WCF service by posting string

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I'm trying to test my sample WCF service by posting a string value using fiddler but it is returning a "405 error". Below is my code

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/json/process", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string ProcessOrderJSON(string request)
{
    return "test json process";
}
```

below is my fiddler data

```
URL: localhost:3173/json/process

User-Agent: Fiddler
content-type: application/json
Host: localhost:3173

RequestBody:
"testdata"
```

below is my config file. please help me in finding out my issue. Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="EmailSettings">
      <section name="Default" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="Appraisal" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="CustomerService" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      <section name="TestAccounts" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MEXGET">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MEXGET" name="Appraisal.OrderService.WCF.OrderServiceMex">
              </service>
    </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" transferMode="Streamed" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="1000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="OrderService.log" />
      <!-- Example using environment variables in params -->
      <!-- <param name="File" value="${TMP}\\ApplicationKit.log" /> -->
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-2p - %m%n" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <LevelMin value="INFO" />
        <LevelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="ErrorsFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="ErrorOrderService.log" />
      <!-- Example using environment variables in params -->
      <!-- <param name="File" value="${TMP}\\ApplicationKit.log" /> -->
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-2p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <LevelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
    <runtime>
          <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                  <dependentAssembly>
                          <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
                          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.1.0" newVersion="2.3.1.0" />
                  </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please tell type of your project? Is it WCF Service Library or WCF Service Application? And please share your *.config file

Comment: It is a WCF service library.. and i edit my question with my .config included

Comment: There is no edit that contains config file details?

Comment: i just added my config file.. sorry for the delay..

Answer (score 0):

405 HTTP status code means that request method not supported by the service. [Detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#405)

Your service method decorated with `WebInvoke` attribute and its `Method` property setted to POST.
If you use GET method to call the service method, then this status code returns.

Change your request method with **POST**.

Comment: i'm using POST in method, i didn't use any get.

Comment: I notice that, your method body is declared also added OperationContract attribute to it. But you should add OperationContract attribute in service  interface. And you cannot declare method body in service interface. Are you sure that you posted true code?

Answer (score 0):

create a simple console application and use WebClient to hit WCF rest service

```
private static void PlaceOrder()
{
   string data = "your string"; 

   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();            
   webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";            
   webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   webClient.UploadString("http://localhost:61090/OrderService.svc
                        /PlaceOrder", "POST", data);              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in config file, you need to explicitly add webHttp endpoint, here is sample of minimum config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <services>
  <service name="WcfServiceLibrary3.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary3.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"/>
  </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And URL in this case will be `http://localhost:8733/web/json/process`

Comment: i tried above config file and when i'm trying to open above UTL (http://localhost:8733/web/json/process) it is saying "Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found."